# How to determine if position Z is within regions with start X and end Y

Tags: java, algorithm, set, jtextarea

I have a JTextArea where the user can create regions using special syntax. I am looking for some assistance in the best way (most efficient using a linear time algorithm) to determine if the current position is within one of the **non-overlapping** regions.

Let's assume I have the following to determine the user defined regions (I scan the document at the start using regex to determine the regions):

```
REGION START = 0, END = 20
REGION START = 21, END = 24
REGION START = 34, END = 40
```

I don't care what region the user is in, I just need to determine if they are in or out of a region, given position X. I could store the regions as an array and loop through the entries until I find one that matches, but this isn't linear time and would take longer if it didn't match a region.

Is there an easier way to do this using an algorithm or storing the data in a certain way?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question correctly... don't you just have to check whether the position is between start and end for any of the regions? Should be linear in the number of regions. Where exactly is the problem, could you provide an example?

Comment: It is linear time. How many regions are we talking about here? 3, 3000, 3000000? If they all fit in a JTextArea, I assume that linear time is fast enough: computing the result will take a few microseconds, and any optimization will be unnoticeable. Anyway, most of the time will be spent parsing the text in the text area. If you really want to speed up things, use proper Region objects, represented, for example, by a JTable. But even then, it smells like premature optimization.

Comment: If the number of regions was constant then it would be a fixed time to check all the regions, agreed. But I am trying to avoid it taking longer as the number of regions increases. I was thinking a Tree or something similar might be able to help as I could pinpoint an area as opposed to checking the whole array, but I am struggling with the concept.

Comment: Maybe use an interval tree (or just store the intervals as pairs of (beginning, size)), search the first interval with a beginning greater than X, check if X is in its predecessor; this will be logarithmic time, but building the tree would be n log n where n is the number of intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the algorithm you are proposing is indeed linear. Here is another one, a bit more complicated, but faster:

- You need to use a Cumulative Table data structure, like Binary Indexed Tree (BIT). A BIT allows you to implement the following operations with logarithmic complexity:

  - Update lo, hi, val: add at the indices [lo, hi] the value val
  - Query x: return the sum at index x
- For each region [lo, hi], you call Update(lo, hi, 1), adding 1 to the appropriate positions in the BIT
- For each query just check if Query(x) is zero. If yes, then x, does not overlap with a region

About Binary Indexed Trees: http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=binaryIndexedTrees

And some code:

```
public class BIT {

  // AddAtPosition: adds at binary indexed tree [bit] the value [v]
  // exactly at position [i]. The binary indexed tree has size [size]

  public static void AddAtPosition(int [] bit, int size, int i, int v) {
    while(i < size) {
      bit[i] += v;
      i += (i & -i);
    }
  }

  // AddAtInterval: adds at binary indexed tree [bit] the value [v]
  // to all position from [lo] to [hi]. The binary indexed tree has size [size]

  public static void AddAtInterval(int [] bit, int size, int lo, int hi, int v) {
    AddAtPosition(bit, size, lo+1, v);
    AddAtPosition(bit, size, hi+2, -v);
  }

  // QueryAtPosition: returns the value of index [i] at binary indexed tree [bit]

  public static int QueryAtPosition(int [] bit, int i) {
    int ans = 0;
    i++;
    while(i > 0) {
      ans += bit[i];
      i -= (i & -i);
    }
    return ans;
  }

  public static void main(String [] args) {
    int [] bit = new int[10+1]; // for values from 0-9
    AddAtInterval(bit, 11, 0, 5, 1);
    AddAtInterval(bit, 11, 4, 7, 1);
    for(int i=0; i<=9; ++i) {
      System.out.print("Query At position " + i + ": ");
      System.out.println(QueryAtPosition(bit, i));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That sounds promising, are you aware of any implementation in Java or would I be looking to write this from scratch?

Comment: That is very helpful and I am not going to try and say I understand fully, but I am getting some unexpected results if I compile your example and add a few more "queryAtPosition" calls. Position 0, 1, 2, 3 and 4 are returning 0 and Position 5, 6 and 7 are returning 1?

Comment: @user1990297 I mainly program in C++, but this time I will make an exception. I will be back with the corrected code :)

Comment: @user1990297 I have edited my answer. I think now it is correct :)

Comment: Thank you, I have used this example as it seems to meet my requirements the best. However, I did have to change the while loop in the "AddAtPosition" method to "while(i < size)" as I was getting "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException".

Answer (score 1):

> I could store the regions as an array and loop through the entries
>   until I find one that matches, but this isn't linear time

[It is linear.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Linear_time)

Assuming that regions are sorted, you could use [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm).

Answer (score 0):

Although I like the BIT example, I think I might use a simpler solution which I am hoping doesn't have a huge performance impact compared to a BIT - is there, considering I need the same length of array to start with? I have defined an array in the same way based on the length of my JText Area:

```
int[] pC = new int[myArea.getText().length()];
```

I then search for my regions and whenever I find a region I set the appropriate position to 1 in my array:

```
for (int i = m.start(); i < m.end(); i++) {
  pC[i] = 1;
}
```

I can then do a simple check against position Z using the following syntax:

```
if (pC[Z] == 0) {
  // OUTSIDE REGION
}
else {
  // INSIDE REGION
}
```

Comment: Although this is a simple solution, it has two main drawbacks: (1) it has pre computation complexity O(I), where I is the largest coordinate in any region (which in many cases can be large). (2) It is static, which means you cannot have any update operations...